# Sqlite, join two query result

Tags: sqlite

I have something like this and I want to get the distinct customer id who ordered Sep and Oct. I have got these two separate queries but can't figure out how to inner join them. I tried union all but it didn't work.

```
select customer_id
from shipping
where transaction_date LIKE '10%'


select customer_id
from shipping
where transaction_date LIKE '09%'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just modify your `WHERE` clause to include both conditions:

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM shipping
WHERE SUBSTR(transaction_date, 1, 2) IN ('09', '10')
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SUBSTR(transaction_date, 1, 2)) = 2
```

By the way, in SQLite dates are stored as text, as there is no formal date type.  You should store your dates as year-month-day, so that they will sort properly.  So instead of using `10/23/15` for 23-October, 2015, you could store `2015-10-23`.

Comment: But that will include customer_id that ordered Oct only and Sep only. What I am looking for is that customers who placed the order in both Oct and Sep.

Comment: @joerna My updated query should work for you, but note that I don't check the year, only the month.